# Save ArrayList in Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am  building a mobile messaging application,

I want to create a chat group where the user selects the members using a checkbox then save the identifiers of the selected users in a list which will be saved in the Firebase database,

The problem that my application crash when I want to save the users to the database

My logcat:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.lang.String

Code:

```
 private void CreateNewGroup(final String groupName) {
        groupNameRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Groups");

        DatabaseReference push = groupNameRef.push();
        String push_id = push.getKey();


        assert push_id != null;
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Groups").child(push_id);

        Map<String, String> hasMap = new HashMap<>();
        hasMap.put("groupName", groupName);
        hasMap.put("Admin", firebaseUser.getUid());
        hasMap.put("members", "");
        ref.setValue(hasMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                Toast.makeText(SelectGroupActivity.this, "Saved" + groupName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        DatabaseReference ref2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Groups" + "/" +
                push_id + "/" + "members");

        SharedPreferences myPref2 = SelectGroupActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("data2", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Set<String> set1 = myPref2.getStringSet("key2", null);

        assert set1 != null;
        ArrayList<String> namesList = new ArrayList<>(set1);
        ref2.setValue(namesList).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
            {
               if(task.isSuccessful())
            {
                Toast.makeText(SelectGroupActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            }
        });
    }
```

And my Model class

```
import java.util.List;

public class Groups
{
    private String groupName;
    private List<String> members;
    private String Admin;

    public Groups() {}

    public Groups(String groupName, List<String> members, String Admin) {
        this.groupName = groupName;
        this.members = members;
        this.Admin = Admin;
    }

    public String getGroupName() {
        return groupName;
    }

    public void setGroupName(String groupName) {
        this.groupName = groupName;
    }

    public List<String> getMembers() {
        return members;
    }

    public void setMembers(List<String> members) {
        this.members = members;
    }

    public String getAdmin() {
        return Admin;
    }
    public void setAdmin(String admin) {
        Admin = admin;
    }
}
```

Database:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't store arrays in firebase. It's either you restructure your database or you store members in string form like `MemberA, MemberB, MemberC` or their id's respectively. So you can do set the members value like below.

```
ArrayList<String> namesList = new ArrayList<>(set1);
String strNameList = "";
for (int i = -; i < namesList.size(); i++) {
    strNameList += namesList[i] + ",";
}

ref2.setValue(strNameList);
```

Or you can restructure your db. I personally recommend this.

```
groups
   groupA
      admin

members
   groupA
      0: "Alpha"
      1: "Bravo"
```

So if you want to know the members of groupA then you can do this.

```
// considering that you have the group name value
// Ex. groupA
database.child("members").child("groupA"). addValueEventListener(...)
```

You can check documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data) on how to structure your data

Comment: Please can you explain more the second solution (My hashset contains the ids of users checked i want to store)